# Concatenar colunas em linhas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando pegar várias colunas e transformá-las em única linha, mas sem sucesso.

Esse é o select que estou tentando fazer:

```
SELECT (`dias2produto`+`dias4produto`) as 'Até 4 dias', round((((`dias2produto`+`dias4produto`)*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_4dias,
       (`dias7produto`) as 'De 5 à 7 dias', round(((`dias7produto`*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_7dias,
       (`dias21produto`) as 'De 8 à 21 dias', round(((`dias21produto`*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_21dias,
       (`dias28produto`) as 'De 22 à 28 dias', round(((`dias28produto`*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_28dias,
       (`dias60produto`) as 'De 29 à 60 dias', round(((`dias60produto`*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_60dias,
       (`dias_endproduto`) as 'Mais de 60 dias', round(((`dias_endproduto`*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_m60dias,
       `total_produto`
```

Tentei fazer usando o group_concat, mas ele colocou tudo em uma única linha e não em linhas separadas. Também procurei saber sobre o Pivot, mas não entendi como usar.

O resultado esperado é esse aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agradeço a atenção de vocês, mas consegui resolver meu problema usando outro modo:

```
SELECT
    CASE    WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 0  AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 2 THEN 'Até 4 dias'
            WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 2 AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 4 THEN 'Até 4 dias'    
            WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 4 AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 7 THEN 'De 5 à 7 dias' 
            WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 7 AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 21 THEN 'De 8 à 21 dias'  
            WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 21 AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 28 THEN 'De 22 à 28 dias' 
            WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 28 AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 60 THEN 'De 29 à 60 dias'     
            WHEN FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) > 60 AND FN_DIFF_DAYS( DATE( t.created ), DATE( f.vencimento )) <= 1000000 THEN 'Mais de 60 dias'
            ELSE 0 END AS `Prazo` ,      
    sum(( f.product_adults + f.product_children + f.product_baby )) AS `Quantidade Geral de Produto`,
    sum(tpf.qt_produto) as qt_produto
```

Consegui pegar um pouquinho de cada dica aqui e formular meu resultado.

♥

Comment: Pode colocar a estrutura da tabela no http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? Se puder colocar dados também, seria até melhor.

Comment: Tá faltando o `SUM( formula )` para agrupar numa linha só. `SELECT SUM( dias2produto + dias4produto) AS 'Ate 4 dias' ...` e o mesmo para o resto. Pesquise por "funções de agregação" - SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, etc

Comment: Você gostaria de concatenar os dados de várias colunas e exibir numa única linha, é isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se quer linha a linha, o caminho é o UNION

```
SELECT SUM(`dias2produto`+`dias4produto`) AS 'Até 4 dias',
       SUM(ROUND((((`dias2produto`+`dias4produto`)*100)/`total_produto`),2)) as p4d
UNION
SELECT SUM(`dias7produto`) as 'De 5 à 7 dias',
       SUM(ROUND(((`dias7produto`*100)/`total_produto`),2) as percentual_7dias
UNION
-- faça novo SELECT para cada linha, com um UNION entre eles --
```

Para pegar os totais de cada select, e não linha a linha, usamos o SUM, que é uma função de agregação.

- SUM para somar todas as linhas
- AVG para achar a média
- MAX para obter o maior valor
- MIN para obter o menor

Tem outras:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

No seu caso:

```
SELECT SUM(`dias2produto`+`dias4produto`) as 'Até 4 dias',
       SUM(ROUND(((dias2produto+dias4produto)*100)/SUM(`total_produto`),2)) as perc_4dias,
       SUM(`dias7produto`) as 'De 5 à 7 dias',
       -- faça isso em todos os casos, note o SUM aqui no total ^tambem ^^^^
```

Dá para escrever de mais de uma maneira:

```
round(((SUM(dias2produto)+SUM(dias4produto)*100)/SUM(`total_produto`),2) as perc_4dias,
      --^^^               ^^^                    ^^^ agrupando campos
round(((SUM(dias2produto+dias4produto)*100)/SUM(`total_produto`),2) as perc_4dias,
      --^^^                                 ^^^ agrupando partes
SUM(round((((dias2produto+dias4produto)*100)/`total_produto`,2)) as perc_4dias,
--^ agrupando tudo
```

Se precisar, pode controlar a agregação com o `GROUP BY`. Pode unir as duas coisas dessa maneira:

```
SELECT SUM( salario ) GROUP BY YEAR( data )
```

Neste caso vai ter os totais, mas separado uma linha por ano em vez de uma linha só.